# How to make production deployment a part of CI/CD pipeline

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build a new pipeline for my project which includes production deployment as a stage. A sample can be seen in the below picture.
[image]

Once the pipeline has passed all the quality gates, it will be deployed to dev environment automatically, and functional test will run in the next stage. There is a manual approval required at this stage, once approved the next step will be deploy to prod/preprod. I am able to achieve the goal till this point. I am stuck at following step:

Can we keep this build forever, or for a specified duration, say, 1 or 2 months, and continue from the same stage when required? For example, the git master branch is getting updated very frequently, and the builds are getting triggered automatically, all builds should reach this stage and wait. Only the build having approval should be able to proceed forward.

There can be one other way; I can have a separate job for deploy to preprod/prod. But, I want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding - Can we keep this build forever, or for a specified duration, say, 1 or 2 months...

You could achive it partially - build could stop at manual step for a period of time. But remember - while job is running it is using executor from agent. Once you use all executors you can't start another build.

... and continue from the same stage when required? - It's not possible.